# Update table with select from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

This update statement is too slow

```
UPDATE planner_ccy a
    SET     dxy =   (SELECT b.close FROM dxy b WHERE b.trade_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY b.trade_date DESC LIMIT 1), 
        usd_rate = (SELECT c.interest_rate FROM usd_ir c WHERE c.set_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY c.set_date DESC LIMIT 1),
        ccy_rate = (SELECT d.interest_rate FROM ccy_ir d WHERE d.set_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY d.set_date DESC LIMIT 1),  
        coal = (SELECT e.price FROM coal e WHERE e.reported_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY e.reported_date DESC LIMIT 1), 
        oil = (SELECT f.price FROM oil f WHERE f.reported_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY f.reported_date DESC LIMIT 1), 
        ump = (SELECT g.ump_rate FROM usd_ur g WHERE g.reported_month <= a.trade_date ORDER BY g.reported_month DESC LIMIT 1), 
        inx = (SELECT h.close FROM inx h WHERE h.trade_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY h.trade_date DESC LIMIT 1)/(SELECT i.gdp FROM fed_ i WHERE i.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY i.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1),
        total = (SELECT j.total FROM fed_ j WHERE j.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY j.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1)/(SELECT k.gdp FROM fed_ k WHERE k.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY k.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1), 
        dfn = (SELECT n.dfn FROM fed_ n WHERE n.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY n.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1)/(SELECT o.gdp FROM fed_ o WHERE o.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY o.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1), 
        tax = (SELECT p.tax_rate*p.tax_bracket FROM usd_tax p WHERE p.set_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY p.set_date DESC LIMIT 1)/(SELECT q.gdp FROM fed_ q WHERE q.reported_year <= a.trade_date ORDER BY q.reported_year DESC LIMIT 1)/1000000000,
        forecast = (SELECT r.close FROM ccyusd r WHERE r.trade_date <= a.trade_date ORDER BY r.trade_date DESC LIMIT MasterSkip,1)

        WHERE a.trade_date >= Start;
```

When I try to use the left join below, only a few rows get updated. How can I use the left join?

```
UPDATE planner_ccy_ a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dxy ORDER BY trade_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS b
    ON b.trade_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM usd_ir ORDER BY set_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS c
    ON c.set_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ccy_ir ORDER BY set_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS d
    ON d.set_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM coal ORDER BY reported_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS e
    ON e.reported_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM oil ORDER BY reported_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS f
    ON f.reported_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM usd_ur ORDER BY reported_month DESC LIMIT 1) AS g
    ON g.reported_month <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM inx ORDER BY trade_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS h
    ON h.trade_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM fed_ ORDER BY reported_year DESC LIMIT 1) AS i
    ON i.reported_year <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM usd_tax ORDER BY set_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS j
    ON j.set_date <= a.trade_date 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ccyusd ORDER BY trade_date DESC LIMIT MasterSkip,1) AS k
    ON K.trade_date <= a.trade_date 

    SET     a.dxy = b.close, 
        a.usd_rate = c.interest_rate,
        a.ccy_rate = d.interest_rate,  
        a.coal = e.price, 
        a.oil = f.price, 
        a.ump = g.ump_rate, 
        a.inx = h.close /i.gdp,
        a.total = i.total/i.gdp, 
        a.dfn = i.dfn/i.gdp, 
        a.tax = j.tax_rate*j.tax_bracket/i.gdp/1000000000,
        a.forecast = K.close

    WHERE a.trade_date >= Start;
```

I need to have a single table updated by selecting from values from multiple tables. Right now the first option that is too slow performs correctly but it is not efficient. I've been reading that joins are more efficient, in fact this query is a migration from a cursor which I had previously and was too slow.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a tough one.  I would probably try actually breaking this update up into several update statements.  I might make one update query for every source table (inx, ccyusd, etc).  Then, issue the queries in parallel.

This will let mysql dedicate more threads to finding all of the data that you want, and then you will have lock contention for the update as threads finish.